# crystal report viewer The Parameter is incorrect

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

i tried to pass parameter to crystal report viewer. but it show The Parameter is incorrect.

`Dim rpt As New ReportDocument`

```
        rpt.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\MAuditList.rpt"
        Dim paramDV As New ParameterDiscreteValue()

        paramDV.Value = frmMachine.machine
        rpt.ParameterFields("@mchno").CurrentValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@mchno").DefaultValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@mchno").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)
        paramDV.Value = frmMachine.batch - 1
        rpt.ParameterFields("@batch").CurrentValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@batch").DefaultValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@batch").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)
        paramDV.Value = InpStdPt
        rpt.ParameterFields("@Points").CurrentValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@Points").DefaultValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@Points").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)
        paramDV.Value = OvrPoints
        rpt.ParameterFields("@ovrpt").CurrentValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@ovrpt").DefaultValues.Clear()
        rpt.ParameterFields("@ovrpt").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)

        Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
        Form1.Show()</code>
```

any error in these code??

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the parameters to your Report object and then assign the report object to your CrystalReportViewer.

Try something like this:

```
'Create report object and load the report
Dim rpt As New ReportDocument()
rpt.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\MAuditList.rpt"

'Set the Parameters
Dim paramDV As New ParameterDiscreteValue()
paramDV.Value = "Parameter Value"
rpt.ParameterFields("@ParameterName").CurrentValues.Clear()
rpt.ParameterFields("@ParameterName").DefaultValues.Clear()
rpt.ParameterFields("@ParameterName").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)

'Assign the report object to the Viewer Report Source
Form1.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
Form1.Show()
```

Comment: i try to declare report, but it show a error. it show red underline below the report()

Comment: @OMG: You will probably need to `Import` the Crystal Namespaces. Try these two `Import CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` and `Import CrystalDecisions.Shared`

Comment: i added them b4, i need to add any reference??

Comment: @OMG: You will need to reference the DLLs.  What is the error message?

Comment: @OMG: Sorry, it should be `ReportDocument`

Comment: i changed report to reportdocument. but it show Object reference not set to an instance of an object at line rpt.ParameterFields("@mchno").CurrentValues.Clear()

Comment: `Dim rpt As New ReportDocument
rpt.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\MAuditList.rpt"
Dim paramDV As New ParameterDiscreteValue()
paramDV.Value = frmMachine.machine
rpt.ParameterFields("@mchno").CurrentValues.Clear()
rpt.ParameterFields("@mchno").DefaultValues.Clear()
rpt.ParameterFields("@mchno").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)
paramDV.Value = frmMachine.batch - 1
rpt.ParameterFields("@batch").CurrentValues.Clear()

rpt.ParameterFields("@batch").DefaultValues.Clear()

rpt.ParameterFields("@batch").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)`

Comment: @OMG: What is the error you are getting? Is it object reference error or Parameter is incorrect? The names of the Parameters must match exactly as they are in the CrstalReport.

Comment: error message is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.i checked the parameters name, parameters name are correct.

Comment: @OMG: I have just created a test app and it works fine. Is the directory path to the report correct? And you have permissions to open the report? Try copying the report in to the local app directory as a test.